# How do I display a specific column from a data vue js + axios?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, pdo

Okay, I'm new to this and have not got the lexicon mastered yet. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I've successfully read the data from my SQL with axios and in (f12) - network - preview. it shows:

[image]

successfully pushed as an array.

But in vue, when I try to display it. it shows: as

```
[ { "COUNT(`char_id`)": "1" } ]
```

How do I display ONLY the "1"?

my vue (inside ):

> {{onlineUsers}}

(inside script)

```
data:() => ({
    onlineUsers: [],
)},
created(){
    this.onlineUsersFunction();
},
methods: {
    onlineUsersFunction: function () {
      axios.post(url, { switchCase: 2 }).then((response) => {
        this.onlineUsers = response.data;
      });
    }
}
```

inside my crud.php

```
$switchCase = (isset($_POST['switchCase'])) ? $_POST['switchCase'] : '';

switch($switchCase){
    case 1: //Select
        $query = "SELECT * FROM login";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $data=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;
    case 2:
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(`char_id`) FROM `char` WHERE `online` = 1;";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $data=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;
        
}
print json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$conn = NULL;
```

Comment: {{ onlineUsers[0]["COUNT(`char_id`)"] }}

Comment: not really a vue issue, you should use [`fetchColumn`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) after changing the query to `SELECT COUNT(\`char_id\`) as users_online FROM..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your count query only returns one row so there's no need to wrap it in an array by using `fetchAll`. Try something like this instead

```php
$query = "SELECT COUNT(`char_id`) FROM `char` WHERE `online` = 1;";
$data = ["count" => $conn->query($query)->fetchColumn()];
```

Then in Vue, simply use

```html
{{ onlineUsers.count }}
```

You should also set `onlineUsers` to be an object at initialisation

```js
data: () => ({
  onlineUsers: {},
)},
```